# C# NHibernate query for any in IList

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I´m trying to query for objects that contains any specified categoryID. If i only use one of my disjunction I get the right result, but not when i combine them.

I want all objects that has CategoryID 1 OR 2 OR 3 AND CategoryID 5. Any suggestions?

Mapping for 'Test': HasMany(x => x.Categories).KeyColumn("PageVersion").ExtraLazyLoad();

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual IList<PageCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class PageCategory
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual int PageVersion { get; set; }
}


    public static Test Query()
    {
        var query = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession().CreateCriteria<Test>();
        query.CreateAlias("Categories", "Categories", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);

        Junction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
        disjunction.Add(Restrictions.In("Categories.CategoryID", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3}));
        query.Add(disjunction);

        Junction disjunction2 = Restrictions.Disjunction();
        disjunction2.Add(Restrictions.In("Categories.CategoryID", new List<int> { 5 }));
        query.Add(disjunction2);

    }
```

Comment: you should add your two `Restrictions.In` to the same disjunction, not create two separate disjunctions.

Comment: Then I get all result with ID 1,2,3,5. I want one for each checkbox-list I´m using, this means item should contain either 1,2,3 AND 5

Comment: Can you show the SQL you want to generate? This will make coming up with the criteria easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `PageCategory` has a reference back to `Test`

```
public virtual Test TestObject { get; set; }
```

and your `Test` class has an `ID` property

```
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
```

you may try :

```
public DetachedCriteria GetDetachedCriteria(List<int> ids)
{
    return DetachedCriteria
            .For<PageCategory>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("ID")))
            .Add(Restrictions.In("CategoryID", ids))
            .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("TestObject", "test.ID"));
}
```

then

```
var pocos = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Test),"test")
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(GetDetachedCriteria(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 })))
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(GetDetachedCriteria(new List<int> { 5 })))
    .List<Test>();
```

**previous answer** ------------------------------

Not sure repeating a CreateAlias would work, but maybe you can try something like this :

```
var query = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession().CreateCriteria<Test>();
   query.CreateAlias("Categories", "cat1", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
   query.CreateAlias("Categories", "cat2", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin);
   query.Add(Restrictions.In("cat1.CategoryID", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3}));
   query.Add(Restrictions.In("cat2.CategoryID", new List<int> { 5 }));
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Then I get the following error: "duplicate association path: Categories

An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: @Tobbe then you should accept the answer. It would be helpful for people encountering the same issue

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @Tobbe Accepting an answer is not the same thing as voting up. You just need to be the question poster to accept the answer.